# Center Vertically Three UILabels inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I have three `UILabels` inside an `UIStackView`. One of them has multiline (last one) and others has only one line. I want them to be centered inside `UIStackView` so that top and bottom spaces can be dynamic. What am I doing wrong?

```
headingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
headingLabel.textAlignment = .center
subHeadingLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
subHeadingLabel.textAlignment = .center
subHeadingLabel.numberOfLines = 0
bodyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
bodyLabel.textAlignment = .center
bodyLabel.numberOfLines = 0
bodyLabel.text = "My very very long text \n to make it multiline"
textStackView.axis = .vertical
textStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
textStackView.alignment = .center
textStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

textStackView.addArrangedSubview(headingLabel)
textStackView.addArrangedSubview(subHeadingLabel)
textStackView.addArrangedSubview(bodyLabel)
```

How It is seen now:

[image]

How It Should be:

[image]

**EDIT:** I also try to do with fillEqually, but It doesn't change anything. I also set top and bottom anchors of UIStackView. What I want to achieve in here is that for example UIStackView has a height of 100 and all three labels has height of 40. That 60 more space should be equally distributed like 30 - 30 on to and bottom.

**Constraints of the UIStackView**

```
myStackView.anchor(contentImageView.bottomAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
```

**One Solution:**
I solve it by putting UIStackView inside an UIView and doesn't give height to UIStackView. Just center X and Y anchors. It solve my problem but I'm not sure If It is a proper solution.

Comment: How did you setup UIStackView by code or in XIB ?

Comment: By code. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `UIStackView` bottom constraint should be greater than equal to zero from `UIViewController`'s view. So that, the `UIStackView` height will be increased based on the content inside it.

Try this.

```
let myStackView = UIStackView()
view.addSubview(myStackView)
myStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myStackView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
myStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
myStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
myStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
myStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
myStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to achieve in here is that for example UIStackView has a height of 100 and all three labels has height of 40. That 60 more space should be equally distributed like 30 - 30 on to and bottom.

That is not how a stack view works. If you want three labels with a height of 40 centered then just do that, with no need for a stack view. Or set the stack view height to 40 and center it.